# how to filter data frame with multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following data frame

```
Time         EQU       ID     VALUE
2022-05-03  202201   AB0125     0
2022-05-03  202201   AB0120     0
2022-05-03  202201   AB0121     0
2022-05-03  202201   AB0122     1
2022-05-03  202201   AB0123     0
2022-05-03  202201   AB0124     0
2022-05-03  202201   AB0125     0
2022-05-03  202201   DE0112     120
2022-05-03  202201   FE0253     23
2022-05-03  202201   GE0223     50
2022-05-03  202201   WW0365     10
```

I want to get data if either of AB0120,AB0121,AB0122,AB0123,AB0124,AB0125 is 1.
How can I filter using python?

Comment: Add the output you expect to your question.

Comment: what are you using to read this dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str.contains` here:

```py
df_out = df[(df["ID"].str.contains(r'^ABC012[0-5]$') & (df["VALUE"] == 1)]
```

Comment: When I run above code, it only returns ABC0120.

Comment: Check your data.  I don't see how this is possible given the sample data you posted above.

Comment: I think I made you confused, I want to filter data to find out any of AB0120,AB0121,AB0122,AB0123,AB0124,AB0125 is 1 from whole data frame which means I want other IDs data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex string contains method with a search to match any string from your desired strings

```py
conditions=["AB0120","AB0121","AB0122","AB0123","AB0124","AB0125"]
df[(df.ID.str.contains("|".join(""), na=False)) & (df.VALUE==1)]
```